# Unpermitted parameters with simple_token_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I have a Participant `model` created in `Rails API Mode`.

This is what the controller of that looks like :

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
    acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

    def create
        binding.pry
        participant = Participant.new(participant_params)
        puts "INFO: ----------------------------"
        puts participant.inspect
        puts params
        if(participant.save)
            render json: {
                status: 'SUCCESS',
                message: 'Participant link created',
                data: participant
            }, status: :created
        else 
            render json: {
                status: 'ERROR',
                message: 'Participant link not created',
                data: participant.errors
            }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private def participant_params
        params.permit(:id_request, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Here is the `User` model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :idcard, presence: true
end
```

The second line you will see this : `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User`

This allows me to add authentication headers in my fetch request in `React`.

This is how I fetch it :

```
participateToContribution = id_request => {
    const data = {
      id_request: id_request,
      user_id: localStorage.getItem('email')
    }
    console.log(data)

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/participants', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-User-Email': localStorage.getItem('email'),
        'X-User-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      data: data
    })
  }
```

I've done this with other controllers and it works well, but now for some reasons when I fetch this rails returns me this error :

```
Started POST "/participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-11 19:08:36 +0200
Processing by ParticipantsController#create as */*
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "titivermeesch@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Unpermitted parameters: :user_email, :user_token
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:7
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:7
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 11ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

I tried to add those 2 fields in the `.permit()` but this gives me another error (I didn't have any of this in my other controllers, and it's just copy pasted).

```
Started POST "/participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-11 19:13:15 +0200
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by ParticipantsController#create as */*
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "titivermeesch@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 56ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)



ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_email' for Participant.):

app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

This is what is sent to this controller from the front-end part :

```
{id_request: 1, user_id: "titivermeesch@gmail.com"}
```

The GitHub code : https://github.com/titivermeesch/neighbourhood-app

`pry` output :

```
     4: def create
 =>  5:     binding.pry
     6:     participant = Participant.new(participant_params)
     7:     puts "INFO: ----------------------------"
     8:     puts participant.inspect
     9:     puts params
    10:     if(participant.save)
    11:         render json: {
    12:             status: 'SUCCESS',
    13:             message: 'Participant link created',
    14:             data: participant
    15:         }, status: :created
    16:     else
    17:         render json: {
    18:             status: 'ERROR',
    19:             message: 'Participant link not created',
    20:             data: participant.errors
    21:         }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    22:     end
    23: end
```

Comment: could you show your `user model`.

Comment: Added in question above.

Comment: could you host your code in github so that it will be easy to debug.

Comment: Here it is : https://github.com/titivermeesch/neighbourhood-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `fetch` with

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/participants', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-User-Email': localStorage.getItem('email'),
    'X-User-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({data)
})
```

}

and data with

```
const data = {
     participant: {

      id_request: id_request,
      user_id: localStorage.getItem('email')
    }
}
```

and `participant_params` as

```
def participants_params
  params.require(:participant).permit(:id_request, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: I already tried with `JSON.stringify(data)` but that don't change anything.
`id_request` and `user_id` are `nil` when I log them in rails.

Comment: are you sure there data is sent as `{id_request: 1, user_id: "titivermeesch@gmail.com"}` from front-end

Comment: Yes, I console logged it and that is what is coming out of it.

Comment: could you add `binding.pry` in `create` method and show the output of `params`

Comment: This is `participant.inspect` and `params` : 
`#<Participant id_request: nil, user_id: nil>
{"controller"=>"participants", "action"=>"create", "user_email"=>"titivermeesch@gmail.com", "user_token"=>"i-x-iGWqg6-rRK2dQGbn"}`
Do I have to install a gem for `binding.pry`?

Comment: sorry you can do it with pry-rails and show me the output

Comment: You can look at the other classes on how they are setup, they are the same but this one still gives me an error

Comment: when I do `binding.pry` it prints out the `create` method and then a `pry` console.

Comment: sorry add the `pry gem` and inside the `create` method do `binding.pry` and call from the `front` end and `print` the `output` of `params` and show

Comment: I added `pry`, the output is above in the answer.  The output of `params` in rails is already in a few messages above.

Comment: sorry could you do this add the pry gem and inside the create method do binding.pry and call from the front end and print the output of params and show so that it is easy in the post it is not using binding.pry properly

Comment: That is exactly what I did, the output of `params` is `{"controller"=>"participants", "action"=>"create", "user_email"=>"titivermeesch@gmail.com", "user_token"=>"i-x-iGWqg6-rRK2dQGbn"}`
In the question above you can see that I added `binding.pry`, and the return of that is at the end of the question.

Comment: so you are not getting user_id and id_request from the front end that why it is nil

Comment: See the updated one send `body` rather than `data` in the `fetch` request

Comment: Oooh, thanks for that :D I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should add those fields (email and token) to your User class. Here we have a complete example for https://gist.github.com/bosskovic/816623404b60b30726a8

Case you already have these fields, you just have to map `user_email` param to `email` column properly.

Comment: Everything is already setup because I have multiple other controllers that work exactly the same as this (4 other controllers that use `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User`) so I don't think the error comes from somewhere else. I'm not using `devise` for authentication

Answer (score 0):

You are not permitting them here

```
private

def participants_params
    params.permit(:id_request, :user_id)
end
```

You have to add them to that array like this

```
private

def participants_params
    params.permit(:id_request, :user_id, :user_email, :user_token)
end
```

Now you said that that threw an error, because `user_email` is not a field on participant.  You will need to add it in order to save a value to it, otherwise you need to take it out of the parameter array getting sent, and then the object will save.  You can't send unpermitted paramters and try to save it, it just won't work.

The only other solution is to re write you create method, but this is not really a solution.

```
def create
  participant = Participant.new
  participant.request_id = params[:participant][:id_request]
  participant.user_id = params[:participant][:user_id]
  if(participant.save)

  ...
```

Comment: This is not how authentication works, `:user_email` and `:user_token` are not linked to `:participant`. Those fields are passed in the header when the request is made to authenticate to the server. These aren't parameters but `headers`

Comment: Well your controller is trying to save those values to that record.  It sounds to me like your form or controller is a little out of line.  So the participant, it only has those two fields `id_request` and `user_id` in my answer above, right?

Comment: Can you post an example of the parameters array getting sent to the controller?

Comment: No the answer is incorrect, but you may be holding something. `Participant` should indeed only save `id_request` and `user_id`, the other 2 values are in the headers and should not be passed as parameters. I added the sent array above.